# Visual Studio 2013 Vertical Brace Lines

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How do you turn off the vertical lines that connect the braces in C# code? Is this a VS 2013 property? Is this resharper 8 doing this? Thanks

Comment: Just a side-note: Indent Guide extension is much more useful http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30 . It displays vertical dotted gray lines, in a very subtle way, which does not interfere with your main editor window.

Comment: I want to turn it on in vs2015......

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Yes, I hate it and was going to ask the same question, but I have figured it out.  You must have ProductivityPowerTools installed too.  Go to Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Other Extensions and there is an option group called Structure visualizer options.  In there is a checkbox for Show code structure in editor.  Turn this off, and job done!

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an extension to add brace highlighting to my project.

Answer (score 35):

**Works for VS2017, VS2019 and VS2022**

Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Uncheck **Show Structure Guide Lines**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For Visual Studio 2017 look at

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> [lang] -> Advanced -> Block Structure Guides

[x] Show guides for declaration level constructs
[x] Show guides for code level constructs

Answer (score 0):

Recently you can find it under Edit -> Outlining

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise now and found this setting under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General, uncheck the box "Show structured guide lines"