# Productivity power tools 2013 remove vertical indent lines

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

I'm using "Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate" and "Productivity Power Tools 2013".
There are these vertical indent lines and I don't know how to remove them.

I tried disabling "Column Guides", but it was not related to this.

Here is an image of what it looks like now:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Found it. It is the "Structure Visualizer" option.
Go to "Tools->Options" and in dialog select "Productivity Power Tools".

It is an option close to the end of the list:

[image: Productivity Power Tools Structure Visualizer]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hated it. I use Indent Guides which is IMO much better than this, at least in C++ code, where it doesn't cut the words like Productivity Power Tools do!

Comment: Timotei - I also prefer the Indent Guides extension (so +1), which also adds guides to JavaScript files, whereas PPT does not
mrzli I also found that you don't have to turn off the Structure Visualiser option, it's enough to just turn off the option mentioned by @Dio Phung in his answer (+1)

Comment: Disabling structure visualizer also disables a useful code map feature, which is better than VS 2013's built-in one (for me). There is a better way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20424258/897326.

Answer (score 10):

VS 2013, I have to include this step:

Tools --> Options --> Productivity Power Tools --> Other Extension --> Turn off "Show code structure in Editor"

Comment: For VS2013, I did not have to uncheck "Show code structure in editor" it went away when i turned "Structure visualiser" off and rebooted VS.

Answer (score 9):

For VS2017 go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->General - uncheck **Show Structure Guidelines**.

Comment: It's Tools → Options... → Text Editor → Display → Show structure guid lines

Comment: Thanks @Muarl - I had missed off Options from the path, have edited my post. You don't need to drill into Display because it's just a group box title on the Text Editor->General page.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2):

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Block Structure Guides -> Disable all`