# remove method "outlining" (dont know what to call it) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with the Productivity Power Tools 2013 extension, which enables you to select/edit multiple or custom themes.

In the PPT extension, you can change just about anything, apart from the thing that i'm trying to change:

[image]

i want to completely remove these lines that indicate the begin/end of the method/namespace.

I basically want it to look like it did in goold old Visual Studio 2012:

[image]

does anyone have any idea how to change/remove this? it might seem like a small thing but it's driving me insane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Productivity power tools 2013 remove vertical indent lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214765/productivity-power-tools-2013-remove-vertical-indent-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be the `Structure Visualizer` option.

Try turning it off using `Tools->Options` /  `Productivity Power Tools` / `Turn Extensions On-Off`.

Comment: stackoverflow to the rescue once again. thanks alot!