# How do I turn off indent guides in VS2015?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I don't seem to be able to find this seemingly simple control.  I believe what I want to remove are VB 'indent guides', but I may even have that terminology wrong.  I'm speaking about the vertical lines in the code editor as shown below:

[image]

I just can't find where the handle is to turn them off.  The various web guides I found suggested places to look, but I didn't have the same menu items as the instructions I read.

Even though I'm using VS2015 I unfortunately found out I have Power Tools for 2013 installed.  Just curious, is that a problem?  I think I did that because I thought the Power Tools have to match the TFS, which is 2013 in this case.  But I think I misread the instructions and could have used a different Power Tools version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214765/productivity-power-tools-2013-remove-vertical-indent-lines) should hopefully answer your question. I believe it's called the structure visualiser.
It should be in Tools / Options / Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: That answer is for VS2013, but I'm fairly certain the way to turn it off is very similar for 2015.