# Is it possible to Add the Notepad++ Open to Close tag Lines to Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, notepad++

I would like to add the lines that Notepad++ has that go from the opening tag to the closing tag to Microsoft Visual Studio.

I have searched all over and cant really find much on this so I thought I would take a shot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This VS Extension does what you want: [Indent Guides Extension - Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)

> Adds vertical lines at each indent level.
>
> ...
>
> Guides can be shown and customized for any language in Visual Studio.

It's also [open sourced on CodePlex](http://indentguide.codeplex.com/) and can be customized if the behavior is not particularly to your liking.

Based on [StackOverflow - Visual Studio 2013 Vertical Brace Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404957/visual-studio-2013-vertical-brace-lines), it appears that a form of this is native to the newest versions of Visual Studio. However, some users don't appear to be fond of its formatting. See [@stevethethread's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20424258/749725)  to that question for how to remove it if you don't like that formatting style.

Comment: This is great thank you. I'm running VS Professional 2012, I'll talk to IT about updating to 2014.